# can't set data to the variable when i parse json

Tags: ios, json, swift, scope

I am currently trying to set data I get from parsing my json to a variable in my `ViewController` from `RawDataCategory` file, which decodes json.

Here is how I call a static method in `CategoryViewController`

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var categoryProducts: [Datum]? // this is the variable i want with data i get
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
  
        Datum.fetchProducts { (categoryProductsFromJSON) -> () in   // here i call a static function.. i will paste the code below

            self.categoryProducts = categoryProductsFromJSON  //here i set value

            print(self.categoryProducts?[0].name) // if i try to print the value in the scope i can access it. and it shows with no problem
        }

            print(categoryProducts?[0].name)  //here is the problem. when i get out of the scope it return nil. 
   
    }
}
```

I can access the variable in the scope but somehow when i try to call it outside it prints `nil`.

Here is the static function (method) i call to get decoded json:

```
    static func fetchProducts(_ completionHandler: @escaping ([Datum]) -> ()) { 

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8888/dayhandan/public/api/v1/category/1") else { return }

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        let task  =  session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return
            }

            do {
                print("no error so far")
                guard let data = data else { return }

                let rawData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CategoryRawData.self, from: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    completionHandler(rawData.data ?? [])
                })

            } catch let err {
                print(err)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

I don't get any errors while i decode json. In fact I can pass it to my `ViewContoller`. There are no errors overall. `categoryProducts` just becomes nil when i call it outside the scope.

**Is this a good way to use decoded data. if it is can someone help me to solve the issue. or can someone point at a good way to use decoded data. Thanks for your time**

Answer (score 2):

You should only try to use the result of `fetchProducts` in the completion handler because the completion handler will be executed at *some point in the future*. Anything outside of the completion handler will be executed immediately.

Reload your `tableView` from within the completion handler:

```
Datum.fetchProducts { (categoryProductsFromJSON) -> () in 
    self.categoryProducts = categoryProductsFromJSON
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Then you should have some logic to populate the `tableView`:

```
extension CategoryViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categoryProducts?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // something like this
        guard let category = categoryProducts?[indexPath.row] else { return UITableViewCell() }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.titleLabel?.text = category.title
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: hey Adam, thanks for your answer. what do you suggest i should do at this point. do you think i should try another approach?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to display the fetched products in your `tableView` so you should reload your `tableView` from inside the completion handler, not outside.